# Change the URL path of parent window in the background without closing the iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I am able to change the parent window from iframe by clicking a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/f7qgp9oy/2/), but as soon as I click on the link, the iframe is also gone. Is there any way to change the path of parent window from iframe in background without closing the iframe?

```
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.onload = function(){

    var link=document.createElement("a");
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Link"));
    link.href = '#';
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.innerHTML = "window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {" +
    "window.postMessage('testMsg', '*');" +
    "}, false);";
    document.head.appendChild(s);
    }
    iframe.src = 'http://example.org';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    window.location.href = "http://jsfiddle.net";}, false );
```

Answer (score 0):

> window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";

Try out This one, Man...!!

Comment: Here, window is already the parent of the iframe I am interested in. I don't have to use window.top. Also, as mentioned the problem is not with redirection. It is to do with the iframe closing after redirection.